# Highlighting specific regions using Matplotlib

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib

I have two arrays `Ii01` and `Iv01` and a list `J`. I am plotting a figure highlighting regions according to the arrays and the list but I also want to highlight other in-between regions (green rectangles) as shown in the expected output.

For example, `Ii01[0][0]=array([0, 9])`, `Iv01[0][0]=array([0.50669985])`. So the rectangle has to be placed between `0` and `9`. But if `Iv01[0][1]= array([2.12339725e-15])`, `Ii01[0][1]=array([6, 1])` which means no rectangle should be placed `6` and `1` since the corresponding value `Iv01[0][1]` is very small (`<tol`).

I also present the current output and the numbering scheme.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm
import math
from  numpy import nan

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=5


N=2*n*(n-1)
tol=1e-9

Ii01=[np.array([[ 0,  9],
       [ 6,  1],
       [ 6,  2],
       [ 6, 11],
       [ 9, 13],
       [ 9, 14],
       [ 9, 18],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  6],
       [11,  2],
       [13, 14],
       [13, 18],
       [14, 10],
       [14, 15],
       [14, 18],
       [15, 10],
       [15, 11],
       [15, 16],
       [16, 11],
       [16, 12],
       [18, 23],
       [23, 24],
       [23, 28],
       [24, 25],
       [24, 29],
       [25, 29],
       [26, 25],
       [28, 24],
       [29, 34],
       [34, 35],
       [34, 39],
       [35, 39]])]


Iv01=[np.array([[5.06699852e-01],
       [2.12339725e-15],
       [4.13550077e-15],
       [1.72227525e-15],
       [1.52373662e-01],
       [1.61074525e-01],
       [3.00835056e-01],
       [6.79487120e-15],
       [4.42370647e-15],
       [2.48130046e-15],
       [6.78627540e-15],
       [1.49159465e-01],
       [1.16222264e-14],
       [1.08774049e-14],
       [1.49159465e-01],
       [1.20229928e-15],
       [7.75023863e-15],
       [4.76121254e-15],
       [3.01398169e-15],
       [3.28881299e-15],
       [6.11446470e-01],
       [3.78156546e-01],
       [1.99429033e-01],
       [1.74136110e-01],
       [3.56893326e-01],
       [1.75675731e-01],
       [1.10401108e-14],
       [1.81009884e-01],
       [5.31835816e-01],
       [1.81335471e-01],
       [3.73570441e-01],
       [1.71352591e-01]])]



J=[[32, 33, 3, 4, 5, 36, 7, 8, 37, 38, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 30]]

for i in range(0,len(J)):
      J[i].sort()


C1=[0]

Path = []
for i in range(0, len(Ii01)):
    uniq = np.unique(Ii01[i][:, 1][None, :])
    #print(uniq)
    uniq = np.sort(np.concatenate((uniq, J[0])))
    print([uniq])
    
    Missing=[]
    for ele in range(uniq[0], uniq[-1]+1):
        if ele not in uniq:
            Missing.append(ele)
    print("Missing =", Missing)
    
    uniq = np.sort(np.concatenate((uniq, Missing)))
    
    y = Iv01[i][:, 0]
    x = Ii01[i][:, 1][:, None] == uniq
    output = np.vstack((np.linalg.lstsq(x, y, rcond=None)[0], uniq)).T
    Path.append(np.insert(output[:, 0], 0, 10))  # fixed inlet
print(Path)    

X=Path[0].reshape(1,N)
X=np.array(X)
print("X =",[X])



for i in range(0,len(X[0])):
        if(X[0][i]<=tol):
            X[0][i]=0.0


X = np.where(X!=0, 10, 0)


for i in range(0,len(X)):
    Max=max(max(X[i]), max(X[i]))
    Min=min(min(X[i]), min(X[i]))
a=Min
b=Max




Amax= math.ceil(Max)
Amin= math.floor(Min)
#print(Amax, Amin)



color = cm.get_cmap('ocean_r')
norm = Normalize(vmin=Amin, vmax=Amax)
color_list = []
for i in range(len(X[0])):
    color_list.append(color(X[0,i]/Amax))
#print(color_list)
id = 0
for j in range(0, n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        ax.hlines(200+200*(n-j-1)+5*n, 200*(k+1)+5*n, 200*(k+2)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id], linewidth=10.0)
        id += 1

    for i in range(0, n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i, 200+200*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        if j < n-1:
            ax.vlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200*(n-1-j)+5*n, 200*(n-j)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id], linewidth=10.0)
            id += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm))
# cb.set_label("Invaded interfaces")
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)

cb.set_ticks([10])
cb.remove() 
plt.title("Invasion Path \n Time = 0.0")
plt.show()
```

The numbering scheme is

[image]

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Comment: What specifically defines where the large transparent green rectangles are supposed to be placed?

Comment: I have now provided an explanation.